# Getting Wrong Answer on CodeSkulptor for same code

Tags: python

In an Online Course during an assignment related to dictionary in python one of my colleague encountered an error in output but it was strange that same code works fine on IDLE and prints the correct code.. The autograger software supports Python 2.7 and is based on Skulpt and CodeMirror so just to test this code i used CodeSkulptor Viz mode which prints incorrect answer. Why is this Hapenning?

```
handle = [ "From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za",
"From louis@media.berkeley.edu",
"From zqian@umich.edu",
"From rjlowe@iupui.edu",
"From zqian@umich.edu",
"From rjlowe@iupui.edu",
"From cwen@iupui.edu",
"From cwen@iupui.edu",
"From gsilver@umich.edu",
"From gsilver@umich.edu",
"From zqian@umich.edu",
"From gsilver@umich.edu",
"From wagnermr@iupui.edu",
"From zqian@umich.edu",
"From antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk",
"From gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com",
"From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za",
"From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za",
"From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za",
"From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za",
"From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za",
"From louis@media.berkeley.edu",
"From louis@media.berkeley.edu",
"From ray@media.berkeley.edu",
"From cwen@iupui.edu",
"From cwen@iupui.edu",
"From cwen@iupui.edu",
    ]

answer_key = 0

dct = dict()
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        email = line.strip().split()[1]
        if not email in dct:
            dct[email] = 1
        else:
            dct[email] += 1

answer_key = max(dct, key=dct.get)
print answer_key, dct[answer_key]
```

Correct Output is 
    cwen@iupui.edu 5

But CodeSculptor prints:
    zqian@umich.edu 4

Comment: are you running the function using `max(dct)`?

Comment: so you get the right answer? and codesculptor gets it wrong? or you get the wrong answer of 4?

Comment: I don't know what CodeSculptor is; if you meant CodeSkulptor, when I copy and paste this code into it, it gives me an error: `Line 41: ValueError: Keyword arguments are not supported by this function`. Since Skulpt is not a complete implementation of Python, I'm not terribly surprised by that.

Comment: And if I [rewrite it slightly to use decorate-search-undecorate](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user37_8hZEmVvltY_0.py) to work around Skulpt not understanding `key` arguments, I get the right answer.

Comment: @ abarnert it is Strange because code works on viz mode.. i.e. on http://www.codeskulptor.org/viz/

Comment: @user308967: From what that page says, it's a beta version. So it makes sense that it would have new features that aren't in the stable version, and that they might not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Skulpt is not a complete implementation of Python, and you're using a feature that it doesn't support: `key` arguments on `max`—or, in fact, any keyword arguments on any function (see [the docs](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#tabs-Python)).

If you try it against the stable version, you get an error:

```
Line 41: ValueError: Keyword arguments are not supported by this function
```

The beta version has apparently added support for this feature, but it's apparently still buggy, which is probably why you're getting the wrong answer. I assume they have a bug reporting system, so you should probably submit a bug on this.

But unless you want to wait until the next version of Skulpt is complete, and a new version of CodeSkulptor rolled out, that won't help you; you'll need to work around the missing/buggy feature. (And make sure to leave a comment reminding yourself, or other readers, why you needed the workaround.)

As the [Sorting HOWTO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) explains, before sorting-related functions (including `max`, even if that isn't obvious) had a `key` parameter, Python programmers had to do something called "decorate-sort (or search)-undecorate": create a new sequence that you've modified (in some reversible way) to sort in the desired order, then call your function, then reverse the modification.

In your case, you want to sort the dictionary in value order. The simplest way to decorate that reversibly is to create a list of `(value, key)` pairs. The `max` of that will be the `value` and `key` for the highest value, and then you want to take the `key`. So:

```
# Skulpt can't handle key arguments on max, so we have to
# decorate-search-undecorate instead.
deco = [(v, k) for (k, v) in dct.items()]
_, answer_key = max(deco)
```

Comment: Keyword arguments have since been implemented. I don't know if it has trickled down to codeskulptor yet. I will look into the key param on `max()`.

Comment: This answer, today, still useful.