# Finding the longest word

Tags: python, list

I have a problem with finding the longest word from list of words in python. I wrote code, but it said:

```
ValueError: Keyword arguments are not supported by this function on line 2
```

Code:

```
def find_longest_word(words_list):
    longest_string = max(words_list, key=len) 
    print(longest_string)
```

Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: How do you use this method ? Please edit and share more code. Because it works well for me

Comment: Do you use `Skulpt` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229868/getting-wrong-answer-on-codeskulptor-for-same-code

Comment: The key argument to `max` was introduced in Python 2.5. Could you be running an older version??

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
from itertools import count

def longwords(l, x):
   c = count()
   return sorted(l, key=lambda i: (len(i), next(c)),
                  reverse=True)[:x]

listA = ['hello','cat','boat','Earth','Moonshine','Aurora','Snowflakes','Sunshine']
n = 8
print(longwords(listA, n))
```

Change the n to find the descending order
You can get more info about lambda in https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp